# How to make all <th> inside of <table> have border on top and bottom?

Tags: html, css

Its my first time using `<table>` so im don't know how to add padding inside of table for `th` and make it have connected padding on top and bottom

HTML

```
<div class="order-list">
  <h3 class="order-tittle">Ваш Заказ</h3>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="list-head">
      <tr>
        <th class="article">Артикул</th>
        <th class="name">Наименование</th>
        <th class="unit">Единица</th>
        <th class="amount">Кол-во</th>
        <th class="price">Стоимость (300руб.)</th>
        <th class="delete">Удалить</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>00000001973</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="td-link">Масло фреоновое B5.2 ( 1 л)</a></td>
        <td>банка</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="10" class="td-input"></td>
        <td class="number-desc">135,00</td>
        <td class="td-button"><button type="button" class="td-button-icon"></button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table td{
border: 1px dotted black;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

.td{
 padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: You already wrote CSS for `.table td` elements, so what's stopping you from writing `.table th{ ... }` ?

Comment: do you want to have padding in ```th``` or do you want it to have border??

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified that you want padding and border bottom and top for `th`
adding the below css snippet to your style.css should do the trick

```
th {
     border-top: 5px solid black;
     border-bottom: 5px solid black;
     padding: 10px;
}
```